# Sharing Whatsapp on Android Webview - return to main actual screen after sharing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview

I am trying to load a website inside the android app using WebView.
I am successfully able to load a website.
I have a button that shares product info on WhatsApp. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GnxB.jpg)

When I click that button it successfully launches Whatsapp and it sends the message after on.
But after sending a message when I return back to my android app(Webview) instead of showing me my website screen it shows me the Whatsapp browser screen. [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97FAa.jpg)

I want that after sharing the info on WhatsApp user should return to screen [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GnxB.jpg) and not [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97FAa.jpg).

**My onCreate() method:**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        brijwasiWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = brijwasiWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        brijwasiWebView.loadUrl("https://brijwasi-bakery.web.app/");
        brijwasiWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url != null && url.startsWith("whatsapp://")) {
                    view.getContext().startActivity(
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.xyxz.xyxz;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
WebView webView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("https://www.example.com");
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView wv, String url) {
if(url.startsWith("whatsapp://"))
{
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(intent);
return true;
}
else
{
return false;
}
}
});
}

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
WebView myWebView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
switch (keyCode) {
case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
myWebView.goBack();
} else {
finish();
}
return true;
}
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
}
```

Comment: This is working for me however after sharing on the blog on WhatsApp it is returning to Whatsapp screen with the message "Send the following on WhatsApp" , not to my blog page which I have shared in WhatsApp. Can you please suggest how to go back to the same page which I have shared on WhatsApp.

Comment: Consider writing your along the answer, this way it will be more readable, also try to better format your code